# Pandas show correlation between three variables

Tags: pandas, dataframe, statistics, seaborn, correlation

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
     CRIME ZIP CODE  VICTIM NAME
0    Murder   90210  Mark
1    Theft    70024  John
2    Robbery  34567  Matthew
3    Assault  00345  Luc
4    .....    .....  .....
```

I need to find out if there is any correlation between the number of crime victims and their zip code. More specifically, I need to plot on a graph if there is a tendency for people in zip codes to suffer more crimes.

How can I do that using pandas and seaborn?

Answer (score 0):

I would first look at the summary statistics. (df is your data frame)

```
df[["CRIME", "ZIP CODE"]].describe()
```

Then I would look the mode

```
df.groupby('CRIME')['ZIP CODE'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I visualize it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like below with an example data:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'CRIME':np.random.choice(['Murder','Theft','Robbery'],100),
                   'ZIP CODE':np.random.choice(['0','1','2','3'],100),
                   'NAME':np.arange(100)})
```

This shows number of crime (no regard to type) by zip code:

```
df["ZIP CODE"].value_counts().plot(kind="bar")
```

[image]

This shows proportion of each crime by zip:

```
pd.crosstab(df['CRIME'],df['ZIP CODE'],normalize="index").plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

[image]